# bash formatting to csv file

Tags: bash

I have a bash ldapsearch in a while loop what I want to write to a csv file.
The ldap listing looks like this:

```
ou=..,dc=..
data1
out=..,dc=..
data2
```

My goal is this format in the csv file:

```
ou=..,dc=..,data1
ou=..,dc=..,data2
```

The problem is with the tr '\n' ',' where it changes the newline, but because of the loop it changes everwhere, causing this:

```
ou=..,dc=..,data1,ou=..,dc=..,data2,
```

How can I replace the newline only before the data?

Comment: Please at least make sure your question looks properly formatted when posted – the original had all three examples looking identical. The site even has a preview box...

Answer (score 0):

One possible way:

```
while read -r dn && read -r data; do
    echo "$dn,$data"
done
```